# Python File doesnt add a text file line onto a variable

Tags: python

I am trying to make a define a variable from a text file

```
    from pathlib import Path
    import linecache
    
    line1 = Path('testing.txt').read_text()
    line1A = linecache.getline("testing.txt", 1)
    answer = line1A
    print(line1A)
    
    test = input("What is 1 + 1? ")
    if test == answer:
        print("Correct")
    else:
        if answer != answer:
            print("Wrong Answer")
Txt File
    2
```

It's never printing the if the answer is right or not

Comment: Under what condition are you expecting `answer != answer` to ever be true?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

A line typically includes a line ending, i.e. a newline character `\n` and the user input won't. So, `test` might be `'2'`, but `answer` will be `'2\n'`.

Why the complications with `Path.read_text()` and `linecache.getline(.., 1)`? That's a lot of plumbing to achieve what `open()` and `next()` could do just as easily:

```
with open('testing.txt') as f:
    answer = next(f).strip()  # this .strip() takes off whitespace, including \n


test = input("What is 1 + 1? ")
if test == answer:
    print("Correct")
else:
    print("Wrong Answer")
```

By the way: `answer != answer` will never be `True`, so you might as well write `if False:` which means you can just leave it out - I assume that was just a mistake.